# why magento2 is Showing multiple images on product detail page?

Tags: magento2, products

[image]why magento2 is showing multiple images on product detail page? I am importing just base image through CSV file. I just want that one image on product detail page. but on product detail page i am getting multiple images that belongs to other products. Here is the file Screenshot

Comment: R u sure that they r not the images of related products... ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your csv file

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir yes! I am sure.

Comment: @MGento now I have provided the sample of Csv file.

Comment: In short wrong images of a product are showing on product detail page.

Comment: Have you created this csv file from the sample which magento admin provides? Also, do you use any third party modules for importing ? Any customization ?

Comment: @MGento yes I created this from sample file. I am using magento import module not any other extension,module or customization.

Comment: Can you open up a chat window here?

Comment: Try to import products using the same file in another fresh magento installation in your local and see if the problem is there also